# Connecting JSP to mysql Xamp Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

I was trying to connect JSP to MySQL and the server am using is Xamp's Tomcat, but all in vain, i have watched all tutorials but they are not working.
1: i have installed JDBC connector too.
2: am working in NET BEANS

files am importing are

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
```

and the method am using is

```
<%
Connection conn = null; 
Statement st = null; 
ResultSet rs = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdetails"); 
st = conn.createStatement();

rs = st.executeQuery("select * from user"); 
while(rs.next()) { %>
<tr>
    <td><% rs.getString("id"); %></td><td><% rs.getString("idd"); %></td>
</tr>  

    <% }

%>
```

and is there any proper way to come to know what is the main error? because i am really not getting it, where am wrong

I have tried ***jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdetails*** also.

Comment: Make sure to add the JDBC connector in WEB-INF/lib folder. If such folder doesn't exists, create it and then add the jar.

Comment: You are missing the username and password for the db... is that correct?

Comment: Also, you should connect to database from a Java class, **NEVER** from JSP directly. Read more about it here: [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197). And, **NEVER** use scriptlets, not even for learning purposes, only for quick dirty tests that will be removed as soon as possible.

Comment: any exceptions raised?